# How can I iterate through the result of itertools.product()?

Tags: python, for-loop, python-itertools

I am trying to implement a Q-Learning algorithm, my state-space contains all possible combinations of numbers 0,1,2 in a vector of a given length.

Now I am trying to initialize a Q-Table full of zeros which would have the same amount of rows as my state-space. And then I want to in each step to run through the state space and check which of all possible state vector is right now. But that means I have to subscript an itertools.product()
How can I do that? because when I try to print it n-th vector from the product it shows an error that product is not subscriptable

I tried this:

```
import itertools
NUMBER_OF_SECTORS = 6
state_space = itertools.product(*[[0, 1, 2]] * NUMBER_OF_SECTORS)
length = len(list(state_space)) # 729
       for obs in range(length):
            print(list(state_space[obs]))
```

Also, is there a possibility, how can I rid the `length` variable? Because when I define the for loop as: `for obs in range(len(list(state_space)))` it is not executed at all.

Thank you very much

Comment: `for i in itertools.product([[0, 1, 2]] * 6): do stuffs`

Comment: Also, `itertools.product([0,1,2], repeat=NUMBER_OF_SECTORS)`. You don't need to precompute the list of lists.

Comment: Ok, Thank you, but there is no way to not-hard-code the for loop iteration range? because this is basically what my state_space variable does, but when I try: for i in state_space: It does not do anything.

Comment: `state_space` is an iterator; passing it to `list` completely consumes it, so there is nothing left to read by the time you try to iterate over it.

Comment: It's also not indexible in the first place; `state_space[obs]` wouldn't give you the `i`th element of the product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only iterate over an instance of `product` once: after that, it is consumed. `list` iterates over the instance in order to produce a list whose length you compute. Once you do that, the state space is gone; all you have left is the length.

You don't need to convert the state space to a list or compute its length; you can just iterate over it directly:

```
state_space = itertools.product([0,1,2], repeat=NUMBER_OF_SECTORS)
for state in state_space:
    print(state)
```